# Null Reference when looping ReturnUrlParsers

Tags: identityserver4

I've created a custom return url parser to determine which tenant is calling the login page, but when loading the login page I get a null reference on one of the returnUrlparsers.

> at IdentityServer4.Services.ReturnUrlParser.ParseAsync(String returnUrl) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Services\ReturnUrlParser.cs:line 38 
>       at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultIdentityServerInteractionService.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(String returnUrl) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Services\DefaultIdentityServerInteractionService.cs:line 54 at IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.BuildLoginViewModelAsync(String returnUrl) in D:\git\identity-server\IdentityServer4\src\Fifthplay.IdentityServer4\Quickstart\Account\AccountController.cs:line 346

I've created a custom implementation of the IReturnUrlParser

```
 public class MyReturnUrlParser: IReturnUrlParser
{
    private IdentityServerConfigurationContext _identityServicecontext { get; set; }
    private ILogger<MyReturnUrlParser> _logger;
    public MyReturnUrlParser(IdentityServerConfigurationContext context, ILogger<MyReturnUrlParser> logger)
    {
        _identityServicecontext = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public bool IsValidReturnUrl(string returnUrl)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationRequest> ParseAsync(string returnUrl)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            return null;

        ... doing some custom stuff 

        return Task.FromResult(authorizationRequest);
    }
```

registered it to DI

```
  services.AddTransient<IReturnUrlParser, MyReturnUrlParser>();
```

When the Login page is loaded I see that the "MyReturnUrlparser" is hit, it return a null because it is just browsing, to the login page but then afterwards a null reference is thrown.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/c2255fae51ecac3048f7281fc7590bee085f30f2/src/Services/Default/ReturnUrlParser.cs

My next guess is that for some reason the default URL parser is null when looping through all available ReturnUrl parsers. Did anybody experience this behavior before? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What is IdentityServerConfigurationContext and how is it created when MyReturnUrlParser is constructed?

Comment: That's a DbContext to query the IdentityServer database.

Comment: An instance of IdentityServerConfigurationContext is registered with DI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default URL parser can't be null because you would have got a `NullReferenceException` on line 36 in ReturnUrlParser.cs:

```
if (parser.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl))
```

Have you pasted the whole stack trace? Is the exception thrown inside the `ParseAsync' method?

One possibility is that a URL parser is returning `true` for a URL that it shouldn't process and is falling over inside the `ParseAsync` because it is encountering something unexpected.  I notice that you always return `true` from `IsValidReturnUrl` which means that your URL parser will be parsing all URLs.

You could try moving your register line:

```
services.AddTransient<IReturnUrlParser, MyReturnUrlParser>();
```

before the call `services.AddIdentityServer()` so that your parser is first in the collection of parser:

[image]